# Peculiarity in the pronunciation of phonological idioms

Tags: idioms

In a thesis on [multi-word units in dictionaries](http://etheses.dur.ac.uk/384/) (page 16; pdf page 38), the researcher touches upon phonological idioms, using the definition:

> a fixed expression which has an oddity of pronunciation

Then he mentions the following examples, noting that the oddity is in the capitalized predicates:

the penny DROPPED

the mind BOGGLES

the plot THICKENS

where the shoe PINCHES

I don’t really get the oddity in those pronunciations. Could you please further explain the idea?

I have done some research on Google, but all I found was that phonological idioms are in fact mostly common among children since they tend to mispronounce the words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The paper actually explains what the oddity is: the capitalised words contain "the nuclear accent", which in English is "the last pitch accent in a prosodic phrase." ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_accent_(intonation)#Nuclear_and_prenuclear_pitch_accents))

> These examples, where the syllable carrying the
>   nuclear accent is capitalised, are: *the penny DROPPED* 'the remark was understood', *the
>   mind BOGGLES* 'I can't comprehend that', *the plot THICKENS* 'the affair becomes more
>   confused' and *where the shoe PINCHES* 'where the difficulty is situated'.
>
> — ALNASER, MOHAMMAD (2010) [Multi-word Items in Dictionaries from a Translator's Perspective.](http://etheses.dur.ac.uk/384/1/PhD.pdf) Doctoral thesis, Durham University

That is, those phrases are always said with the accent on that word, even where (say) the *plot* is obvious and one might expect that word to bear the accent. In "the plot thickens" — and the other expressions — it never does; the capitalised words are always accented.

Indeed, when the noun is accented, it only serves to emphasise the idiom: "Well, the **plot's** thickened, even though the fog has cleared."

Comment: How odd. I can perceive no difference in pitch, accent, or stress between these idioms and comparable non-idiomatic utterances. I don't see how they're phonological idioms at all…